# Variáveis do JavaScript no HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite, tenho um arquivo HTML e preciso exibir na pagina algumas variáveis que estão no meu JavaScript, como eu poderia fazer esta conexão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="idQueIdentificaP"></p>
  <button type="button" onclick="alterar()">alterar de novo</button>
</body>

</html>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#idQueIdentificaP').text('JAVASCRIPT ALTEROU ESSE P')
});


function alterar(){
$('#idQueIdentificaP').text('JAVASCRIPT ALTEROU ESSE P DE NOVO')
}
```

Veja esse exemplo simples com Jquery: [aqui](https://plnkr.co/edit/rRHefUR74E1rm5VaSOHJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

***Boa tarde. Talvez isso pode ser útil:***

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1 class="jsH1"></h1>
    <input type="text" class="jsInput">
  </div>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        //Nós definimos variáveis
        var h1Content = 'Titulo pra o H1';
        var inputContent = 'Valor do input';

        //Nós carregamos as variáveis anteriores para seus respectivos contêineres
        $('.jsH1').text(h1Content);
        $('.jsInput').val(inputContent);

     })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar jQuery como foi publicado aqui ou fazer isso com apenas o Javascript com o *innerHTML*.

```
<div id="campo1"> 
a
</div>

<script>
variavel = 5;

document.getElementById("campo1").innerHTML = 'Valor da variavel: '+variavel;
</script>
```

**innerHTML** é utilizado para pegar ou setar todo o HTML de um determinado elemento da pagina, no nosso caso foi da div que tem o id campo1